# How to understand the big-o of a program if the power of n is smaller than zero

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Let's say we have a for loop which is starting from 0 to all the way to the 100 ( or some constant ) divided by variable n, what will be the Big-O notation in this case?

Unlike other cases, if we increase our n, our program's runtime will be faster. Also the opposite situation is also problematic, if we decrease our n, our program is getting bigger and bigger, which I couldn't associate with the nature of Big-O notation

```
for( int i = 0; i < 100 / n ; i ++ );
```

As I mentioned, I obviously I am getting the reverse result I was expecting.
( as n increases program goes faster and as n decreases program goes slower )

Comment: This is `O(C)` which is equivalent to `O(1)`. In your case `C == 100`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the loop is running to a fixed value (100) the run time will be constant `O(1)` this is given that `n >= 1`.

If n is a positive fraction it could potentially make the loop longer so in that case I'd say that the run time is `O(1/n)` given `0 < n <= 1`.

Comment: I thought about that, but isn't saying O(1) is the same thing as saying that the run-time of program is not bounded to the "n" ?

Comment: Which is true. The run time of the program is bounded by a fixed value not n. If n > 1

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the answers and comments you have received so far, the runtime of your program is certainly O(1). But that is not tight. It is true in the same sense that the runtime of a linear search is O(n<sup>2</sup>) as well as O(2<sup>n</sup>).

The tight upper bound to your program's runtime is O(1/n). In fact, you program's runtime is Θ(1/n).